# x86 show the rest of the output (inlining)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

The following code is suppose to have display if which number is greater or if they are both equal and the sum, but all I get is just the sum and if I delete the the sum part the first part displays, showing whether or not the numbers are equal

```
section .rodata                                                                                                                
          prompt1    db "Enter an integer: ",0   ; 0 is null character                                                                   
          prompt2    db "Enter another integer: ",0                                                                                      
         num_format db "%ld",0                                                                                                          
          format_str1 db "The greater of %ld and %ld is %ld.",10,0  ; 10 is LF                                                           
          format_str2 db "The sum of %ld and %ld is %ld.",10,0  ; 10 is LF                                                               
          equalprompt db "%ld and %ld are equal.",10,0  ; 10 is LF                                                                       

          section .text                                                                                                                  
          global main              ; main and _start are both valid entry points                                                         
          extern printf, scanf     ; these will be linked in from glibc i                                                                

          main:    
          ; prologue                                                                                                                     
          push    rbp          ; save base pointer to the stack                                                                          
          mov     rbp, rsp     ; base pointer = stack pointer                                                                            
          sub     rsp, 16      ; make room for two long integers on the stack                                                            
          push    rbx          ; push callee saved registers onto the stack                                                              
          push    r12          ; push automatically decrements stack pointer                                                             
          push    r13                                                                                                                    
          push    r14                                                                                                                    
          push    r15                                                                                                                    
          pushfq               ; push register flags onto the stack                                                                      

          ; prompt for first integer                                                                                                     
          mov    rdi, dword prompt1    ; double word is 4 bytes; a word is 2 bytes                                                       
                                       ; rdi = 32-bit address of prompt1                                                                 
          xor    rax, rax              ; rax is return value register - zero it out                                                      
          call   printf                ; call the C function from glibc                                                                  

          ; read first integer                                                                                                           
          lea    rsi, [rbp-8]          ; load effective address - this instruction                                                       
                                       ; computes the address 8 bytes above the                                                          
                                       ; base pointer - the integer read by scanf                                                        

          mov    rdi, dword num_format ;                                                                                                 
          xor    rax, rax              ; zero out return value register                                                                  
          call   scanf                 ; call C function                                                                                 
                                      ; scanf reads the input as an integer                                                              

          ; prompt for second integer                                                                                                    
          mov    rdi, dword prompt2                                                                                                      
          xor    rax, rax                                                                                                                
          call   printf                                                                                                                  

          ; read second integer                                                                                                          
          lea    rsi, [rbp-16]                                                                                                           
          mov    rdi, dword num_format                                                                                                   
          xor    rax, rax                                                                                                                
          call   scanf                                                                                                                   

          ; determine if num2 (second integer) is greater than num1 (first integer)                                                      
          xor     rbx, rbx      ; RBX = 0x0                                                                                              
          mov     rax, [rbp-16] ; RAX = num2 ; load rax with value at rdb-16                                                             
          cmp     rax, [rbp-8]  ; compute (num1) - (num2) and set condition codes                                                        
          ; in machine status word register based on result                                                                              
          jl     lessthan      ; jump if num1 <= num2                                                                                    
          je      equal                                                                                                                  

         ; num1 > num2                                                                                                                  
          mov     rdi, dword format_str1                                                                                                 
          mov     rsi, [rbp-8]     ; num1 
          mov     rdx, [rbp-16]    ; num2                                                                                                
          mov     rcx, [rbp-16]    ; greater of the two                                                                                  
         ;mov     rcx, 0                                                                                                                 
          ; add     rcx, rsi                                                                                                             
          ; add     rcx, rdx                                                                                                             
          ; xor     rax, rax                                                                                                             
          jmp sum                                                                                                                        

          lessthan:                                                                                                                      
          ; num1 < num2                                                                                                                  
          mov     rdi, dword format_str1                                                                                                 
          mov     rsi, [rbp-8]   ; num1                                                                                                  
          mov     rdx, [rbp-16]  ; num2                                                                                                  
          mov     rcx, [rbp-8]   ; greater of the two                                                                                    
         ;mov     rcx, 0                                                                                                                 
         ;add     rcx, rsi                                                                                                               
          ;  add     rcx, rdx                                                                                                            
          ;  xor     rax, rax                                                                                                            
         jmp     sum                                                                                                                    

         equal:                                                                                                                         
         mov     rdi, dword equalprompt                                                                                                 
         mov     rsi, [rbp-8]   ; num1                                                                                                  
         mov     rdx, [rbp-16]  ; num2                                                                                                  
         jmp     sum                                                                                                                    

         sum:                                                                                                                           

         mov    rdi, dword num_format ;                                                                                                 
         mov     rdi, dword format_str2                                                                                                 
         mov     rsi, rsi   ; num1                                                                                                      
         mov     rdx, rdx  ; num2                                                                                                       
         mov     rcx, 0                                                                                                                 
         add     rcx, rsi                                                                                                               
         add     rcx, rdx                                                                                                               
         jmp exit                                                                                                                       

         exit:                                                                                                                          
         call    printf                                                                                                                 
         ; epilogue                                                                                                                     
         popfq                                                                                                                          
         pop     r15                                                                                                                    
         pop     r14                                                                                                                    
         pop     r13                                                                                                                    
         pop     r12                                                                                                                    
         pop     rbx                                                                                                                    
         add     rsp, 16        ; set back the stack level                                                                              
         leave                                                                                                                          
         ret
```

The sample output is this:

```
Enter an integer: 7                                                                                                                        
Enter another integer: 3                                                                                                                   
The sum of 7 and 3 is 10
```

Comment: Please remove the line numbers so other users can assemble your code and plug it into a debugger.

Comment: `call printf` on line 120 can only do one or the other. I think you should add another `call printf` on line 109.

Comment: You don't need to preserve FLAGS in a function, they're call-clobbered like `rcx`, `rdx` and so on.  Also, you don't need to push/pop registers you never touch (like `r12`).  It's just a wasted instruction, just like `jmp exit` / `exit:`.  You don't need to jump over an empty line; execution always goes to the next instruction anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov rax, [rbp-16] ; RAX = num2 ; load rax with value at rdb-6
> cmp rax, [rbp-8]  ; compute (num1) - (num2) and set condition code
> jl   lessthan      ; jump if num1 <= num2
> je   equal
> ```

The comments starting at this `cmp` are mostly wrong (inversed)!
What `cmp` computes is `RAX - [rbp-8]`, so *num2* - *num1*.
Your `jl lessthan` jumps if *num2* < *num1*.
Luckily the code that fills in the greater of the two in the snippets that follow is correct.

---

When the code arrives at the label *sum*, you immediately start by destroying your carefully set up `RDI` register. You should firstly issue a `call printf` to display the first line of results showing the greater number. Hereafter you can setup for the second line of results showing the sum.

---

Why don't you simplify the code a bit? You could start by putting *num1* in `RSI` and *num2* in `RDX`, and then compare these registers instead of doing it in `RAX` and later having to load these registers repeatedly.
Also don't be afraid to do some seemingly useless operations if by doing so you can reduce the number of branches in your program. See how next code loads `RDI` and maybe later has to reload it with another value? Same thing with loading `RCX` and maybe having to reload it over again.

```
    mov     rsi, [rbp-8]  ; num1 
    mov     rdx, [rbp-16] ; num2             
    cmp     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdi, dword equalprompt                            
    je      sum
    mov     rdi, dword format_str1                            
    mov     rcx, rsi      ; num1 is greater of the two
    jg      sum           ; jump if num1 > num2        
    mov     rcx, rdx      ; num2 is greater of the two      
sum:
    call    printf
```

> ```
> mov     rcx, 0
> add     rcx, rsi
> ```

There's no point in doing it this way. Simply `mov` the first number into `RCX` using `mov rcx, rsi`.

```
    mov     rdi, dword format_str2
    mov     rcx, rsi
    add     rcx, rdx
    call    printf
```